# How to run Multiple instance of chrome to run all the scenarios in sequence of single feature file in protractor

Tags: typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

I want all the scenarios to run in multiple instance of browser, i have tried giving max instance in capabilities but it always open 1 instance of chrome and run the tests one by one. I want tests to run in multiple instances of chrome. What am i doing wrong here ?

Current config file:

```
     exports.config = {
      allScriptsTimeout: 800000,
      getPageTimeout: 400000,
      specs: [
        './src/cucumber/features/**/memberSearch.feature',
      ],
      params: {
        pageObjects: require['./src/cucumber/pages/**/*.po.ts'],
        customTimeout: 5000,
        url:{
          dev: "https://dev.com/login",
          test: "https://test.com/login",
          stage: "https://stage.com/login",
          local: "http://localhost:4200",
        }
      },
      capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        //acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 4,
        chromeOptions: {
          args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800x600'],
        },
      },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'https://dev.com/',
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  cucumberOpts: {
    compiler: 'ts:ts-node/register',
    require: ['./src/cucumber/steps/**/*.steps.ts', './src/cucumber/utils/**/*.util.ts'],
    format: 'json:./reports/cucumber_report.json',
    monochrome: true,
    strict: true,
    tags: '@MemberSearch',
  }
```

Feature File:

```
    @MemberSearch
Feature: Search a member
  @CompletedTodo
  Scenario: See all the assessments associated with the member
    Given Enter the URL
    When  click on the MemberID radio Button
    And   Type the memberID "ABCD" first time
    And   Click the Search Button first time
  
@FilterTitle
  Scenario: Validate the Filters With Title field
    Given Enter the URL
    When  click on the MemberID radio Button
    And   Type the memberID "ABCD"
    Then  Click the Search Button
  
@FilterTimeFrame30
 Scenario: Validate the Filters with time FilterTimeFrame 30
   Given Enter the URL
    When  click on the MemberID radio Button
    And   Type the memberID "ABCD"
    Then  Click the Search Button
    Then  Show the message "No records to display"
  
@FilterTimeFrame60
 Scenario: Validate the Filters with time FilterTimeFrame 60
   Given Enter the URL
    When  click on the MemberID radio Button
    And   Type the memberID "ABCD"
    Then  Click the Search Button
  
@FilterTimeFrame90
 Scenario: Validate the Filters with time FilterTimeFrame 90
   Given Enter the URL
    When  click on the MemberID radio Button
    And   Type the memberID "ABCD"
    Then  Click the Search Button
    Then  Show the message "No records to display"
    And   Click the Clear Button
  
@FilterTimeFrame365
 Scenario: Validate the Filters with time FilterTimeFrame 365
   Given Enter the URL
    When  click on the MemberID radio Button
    And   Type the memberID "ABCD"
    Then  Click the Search Button
    Then  Show the message "No records to display"
    And   Click the Clear Button
    When  Type the memberID "40988"
```

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXTwa.png)

I want all the scenarios run in multiple instance of browser, i have tried giving max instance in capabilities but it always open 1 instance and run the tests one by one. I want to tests to run in multiple instances. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: are you using cucumber-js here?

Comment: yes i am using using cucumber

Comment: Update: If i use multiple feature files then i am able to launch multiple instance of browser(1 feature file = 1 browser instance is what i understood so far) but when i give path of only 1 feature file in spec it only launches 1 instance of browser. Is this normal behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using '--parallel=**' in your npm/protractor script (for ex: cucumber-js ./features --parallel=5). Replace ** with number of parallel instances you need. 'maxInstances' in config file refers number of instances at max a browser should launch, it does not mean 4 instances will open by default, change it according to --parallel count.

--parallel in cucumber-js runs each scenario of same feature file and each example of one scenario outline triggers in parallel.

Comment: can you point me to some documentation or an example as i am fairly new to Protractor. Thanks.

Comment: for ex: define package.json scripts as { "test": "cucumber-js ./src/test/features --browser=chrome --env=test --parallel=5 --tags=@testTag"  }. Later if you execute  'npm run test' command, it triggers all your scenario's tagged with @testTag in parallel. As we defined 5 with parallel, 5 parallel instances will be opened if we have 5 or more than 5 scenario's matching with the tag. In case matched scenario count is less than 5 (for ex: 3), it launches only 3 instances instead of 5..